# SFINAE and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, sfinae

I'm looking for a solution to a following problem:

```
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, void>::type foo(T val)
    {
        printf("std::string\n");
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Arg>
    static void multiple(Arg&&... arg)
    {
        T::foo(arg...);
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, void>::type foo(T val)
    {
        printf("int\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    int b = 0;
    A::multiple<B>(a, b);
}
```

All works fine if both `foo` methods are in the same class or I force `foo` from proper class (`A::foo` for `std::string` and `B::foo` for `int`), however I need more than one class, because base class must be extendable. I can't use simple specialization, because I need more SFINAE features like detect for `std::pair`, `std::tuple` etc. I also don't want to move foo methods from a class to a namespace. Do you have any Idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you even need all this SFINAE'ing in the first place? Plus, What's with the "multiple" method, when you only specialize for a single-parameter foo?

Comment: this is just a simple example for more advanced purpose, I'm working on data types converter and 'multiple' is required because I want to convert all types in a single call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `B::foo` hides `A::foo`, you need a `using`:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::foo;

    template <typename T>
    static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, void>::type foo(T val)
    {
        printf("int\n");
    }
};
```

But

From [namespace.udecl#15.sentence-1](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#15.sentence-1):

> When a using-declarator brings declarations from a base class into a derived class, member functions and member function templates in the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member function templates with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (if any) in a base class (rather than conflicting)

Return type doesn't count, so you have to use `std::enable_if` in parameter:

```
class A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static void foo(T val, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, int> = 0)
    {
        printf("std::string\n");
    }

};

class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::foo;

    template <typename T>
    static void foo(T val, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value, int> = 0)
    {
        printf("int\n");
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r-ThCj)

Note: you also have typo for

```
template<typename T, typename... Arg>
static void multiple(Arg&&... arg)
{
    T::foo(arg...); // B::foo(string, int)
}
```

which should be

```
template<typename T, typename... Arg>
static void multiple(Arg&&... arg)
{
    (T::foo(arg), ...); // B::foo(string), B::foo(int)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally forgot about methods hiding. I also had to move 'enable_if' to parameters to make this code works under clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5309915ef99d8d4

Comment: You might read [overload-resolution-between-template-members-in-base-and-derived-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45589662/2684539) for the reason of your fix, as gcc is wrong, and clang is correct.